# drop table and insert records from a new select statement (with the correct records)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I will like to drop an existing table and insert new records from a select statement. Keeping the coulmns the same. Old table (column a, column b) and select statment (select from a,b,c,d  with inner joins)

Comment: So, you want to keep the records from the table you want to drop creating a new table with other fields? Is that it?

Comment: I will like drop the table completely and insert new records from the select statement or add records from the select statement without dropping the table. I can add a where clause to the select statement, whichever is faster)

Comment: SELECT a.me
,b.you
,c.them
,c.us
FROM A
INNER JOIN TABLE b ON a.1 = b.1 collate Latin1_General_CI_AI
INNER JOIN Table c  
ON b.1 = c.1
where date between '2014-07-21 09:00:00.000' and '2014-07-23 09:00:00.000') I want to use add a and b to a new table or delete table entirley and insert all a and b results without the where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to drop completely you can do this:

```
   Drop table yourtable

   SELECT *
   INTO yourtable
   FROM 
   (SELECT a  ,  b FROM blah, blah) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to change the schema of your old table, you might try a `TRUNCATE TABLE`:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable
```

Then you can insert into this table with a SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
(
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB,
    ...
)
SELECT
    ValueA,
    ValueB,
    ...
FROM 
    Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
    ON Table2.SomeColumn = Table1.SomeColumn
...
```

On the other hand, if you really want to recreate the table, then you can `DROP TABLE` and re-create it with a `SELECT INTO` as Jayvee showed.